# Google Directions Not returning optimized route

Tags: ios, google-maps, optimization, maps

I have an app that lets the user generate a route using a origin/destination point and waypoints in between. If I submit the url without optimized:true in it I get a polyline back that goes to each waypoint in the order sent.

If I add optimized:true to the query then I get, in this case, an error for my second waypoint (zero_results) which crashes the app. In both submissions I am sending address city, st zip for each waypoint.

My initial url (decoded) looks like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=115 E Main St, Monrovia, IN 46157, USA&destination=115 E Main St, Monrovia, IN 46157, USA&waypoints=234 E SOUTHERN AVE INDIANAPOLIS, IN 46225|208 MEADOW DR DANVILLE, IN 46122|485 N INDIANA AVE SELLERSBURG, IN 47172|1111 RONALD REAGAN PKWY STE C1400 AVON, IN 46123|651 S CLARIZZ BLVD BLOOMINGTON, IN 47401&key=KEY GOES HERE
```

Partial JSON return:

```
"geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJXZBHhT-WbIgRPl_LqYqD4hc",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJuZ2FWEBaa4gRuP_y0qBGYx0",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EiYyMDggTWVhZG93IERyLCBEYW52aWxsZSwgSU4gNDYxMjIsIFVTQQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-2zWpAhwaYgRbGCpQlasryo",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EjIxMTExIFJvbmFsZCBSZWFnYW4gUGt3eSBjMTQwMCwgQXZvbiwgSU4gNDYxMjMsIFVTQQ",
         "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJV8KIRiNkbIgRZVxX1emoBQU",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJXZBHhT-WbIgRPl_LqYqD4hc",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
```

My optimized url looks like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=115 E Main St, Monrovia, IN 46157, USA&destination=115 E Main St, Monrovia, IN 46157, USA&waypoints=optimized:true|234 E SOUTHERN AVE INDIANAPOLIS, IN 46225|208 MEADOW DR DANVILLE, IN 46122|485 N INDIANA AVE SELLERSBURG, IN 47172|1111 RONALD REAGAN PKWY STE C1400 AVON, IN 46123|651 S CLARIZZ BLVD BLOOMINGTON, IN 47401&key=KEY GOES HERE
```

Full JSON:

```
{
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJXZBHhT-WbIgRPl_LqYqD4hc",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJuZ2FWEBaa4gRuP_y0qBGYx0",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EiYyMDggTWVhZG93IERyLCBEYW52aWxsZSwgSU4gNDYxMjIsIFVTQQ",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJ-2zWpAhwaYgRbGCpQlasryo",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "EjIxMTExIFJvbmFsZCBSZWFnYW4gUGt3eSBjMTQwMCwgQXZvbiwgSU4gNDYxMjMsIFVTQQ",
         "types" : [ "subpremise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJV8KIRiNkbIgRZVxX1emoBQU",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJXZBHhT-WbIgRPl_LqYqD4hc",
         "types" : [ "street_address" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}
```

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing `optimize:true` instead of `optimized:true`

Here's the working URL when I compared the 2 URLs you provided.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=115%20E%20Main%20St,%20Monrovia,%20IN%2046157,%20USA&destination=115%20E%20Main%20St,%20Monrovia,%20IN%2046157,%20USA&waypoints=optimize:true|234%20E%20SOUTHERN%20AVE%20INDIANAPOLIS,%20IN%2046225|208%20MEADOW%20DR%20DANVILLE,%20IN%2046122|485%20N%20INDIANA%20AVE%20SELLERSBURG,%20IN%2047172|1111%20RONALD%20REAGAN%20PKWY%20STE%20C1400%20AVON,%20IN%2046123|651%20S%20CLARIZZ%20BLVD%20BLOOMINGTON,%20IN%2047401
```

Comment: I had actually asked this on another forum and realized my mistake but thanks for the assist. Stupid syntax. :D